# PHP - finding the filesize of a blob

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a blob, which I've got using:

```
 $blobData = $this->getBlobData();
 $imageStream = stream_get_contents($blobData);
```

so when I  var_dump($imageStream) I get a load of chars, which I'm guessing in the binary form of the image.

What I'd like to do, is get the imagesize, in terms of width and height for this blob image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($imageStream);
echo imagesx($image);
echo imagesy($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a "dummy" file that collects the requested image from the db and displays it. Then just do

```
getimagesize("/path/to/file/img.php?id=".$id);
```